# test if object was successfully added to an array junit

Tags: java, arrays, object, junit

I am trying to add a Spherocylinder object to an array. Afterwards I would like to test it in junit to verify that the object was successfully added to the array. The issue I am running into is whenever I try to run my junit test, I get an out of bounds exception error. Here is the code from my method.

```
public class SpherocylinderList {

//instance variables.
   private String listName;
   private Spherocylinder[] sList;
   private int numberOfSpherocylinders;

   /**
    *Constructor for SpherocylinderList.
    * @param listNameIn - incoming objects.
    * @param sListIn - name of list.
    * @param numberOfSpherocylindersIn - number of objects.
    */
   public SpherocylinderList(String listNameIn, Spherocylinder[] sListIn, 
      int numberOfSpherocylindersIn) {

      listName = listNameIn;
      sList = sListIn;
      numberOfSpherocylinders = numberOfSpherocylindersIn;
   }

/**
    * Method to return total number of Spherocylinders.
    * @return numberOfSpherocylinders - total number of ojbects.
    */
   public int numberOfSpherocylinders() {
      return numberOfSpherocylinders;  
   }

public void addSpherocylinder(String labelIn, double radiusIn,  
      double cylinderHeightIn) {

      Spherocylinder s = new Spherocylinder(labelIn, radiusIn, 
         cylinderHeightIn);
      sList[numberOfSpherocylinders] = s;
      numberOfSpherocylinders++;
   }
```

and here is my Junit Test method.

```
@Test public void addSpherocylinderTest() {
      Spherocylinder s1 = new Spherocylinder("Small Example", 0.5, 0.25);
      Spherocylinder s2 = new Spherocylinder("Medium Example", 10.8, 10.1);
      Spherocylinder s3 = new Spherocylinder("Large Example", 98.32, 99.0);
      Spherocylinder[] sList = {s1, s2, s3};
      SpherocylinderList s = new SpherocylinderList("test", sList, sList.length);
      s.addSpherocylinder("test2", 10.9, 10.2);
      Assert.assertEquals(4, s.numberOfSpherocylinders());
   }
```

I am getting the error

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException: 3
```

When I run my test. How do I properly test adding the object? I also want to add that I cannot use an ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

Your ´sList´ is an array with a fixed dimension (3 elements). You cannot increase an array once it is allocated. You have to allocate a new one. I suggest you to use an ArrayList instead of your array.

Answer (score 0):

When the SpherocylinderList object is created, its sList array is initialized to only have space for the 3 elements that are provided to it.

When another element is added in the addSpherocylinder(string, double, double) method, it tries to access sList[3], but since sList was initialized to only have three spots (at indices 0,1, and 2), this throws an out of bounds exception.

One approach may be to use an arrayList instead of an array for sList, because the capacity is automatically increased when an item is inserted after its capacity is reached.

`private ArrayList<Spherocylinder> sList;`

If you choose to do this, this line in the constructor

`sList = sListIn;` can be replaced with `sList = new ArrayList(sListIn);`

And this line in the addSpheroCylinder method `sList[numberOfSpherocylinders] = s;` can be replaced with `sList.add(numberOfSpherocylinders, s)`

Comment: I like that approach, but unfortunately I have to solve this problem using arrays and not ArrayList.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20427213/possible-to-add-more-values-to-a-full-array) provides a solution to add an item to a full array, maybe it is more along the lines of what you're thinking?